# how can I put a div inside of another div that is sitting next to a div that has a float: left property?

Tags: html, css

The question is confusing but I just want to put the 'signIn' css selector inside the 'headerRightPanel' selector and have it span that width. That is grow and shrink within it. now headerRightPanel is sitting next to headerLeftPanel which has the Float: left property. and for some reason the sign in div is expanding the whole entirety of the header which i dont want.

how can I just keep sign in inside headerRightPanel and have it expand the whole section?

```css
html{
    height: 900px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}

body{
    height: 885px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}


.MAINPAGE{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 870px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.HEADER{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 175px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.headerLeftPanel{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}

.headerRightPanel{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 160px;
    margin: 5px;
}

.signIn{
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="MAINPAGE">
      <div class="HEADER">
        <div class="headerLeftPanel">
          
        </div>
        <div class="headerRightPanel">
          <div class="signIn">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `headerRightPanel` element has no width set on it, so, even if it floats around the `headerLeftPanel`, it takes up 100% width. and so does its child, the `signIn` element. You could set the right panel to 25% or you could use `display: flex;` on the `HEADER` element to position both elements instead of the float.

Comment: It would help if you put some text in your example divs. When I "Run code snippet" I am not sure which are the divs you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below things

- give .headerRightPanel float: right; position: relative:
- set .signIn maxWidth: 100%;

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to solve it with `flex`:

```css
html {
  height: 900px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

body {
  height: 885px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
}

.MAINPAGE {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 870px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.HEADER {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* All children shall flex */
  display: flex;
}

.headerLeftPanel {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 75%;
}

.headerRightPanel {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 160px;
  margin: 5px;
  /* This item shall fill remaining space */
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.signIn {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="MAINPAGE">
  <div class="HEADER">
    <div class="headerLeftPanel">

    </div>
    <div class="headerRightPanel">
      <div class="signIn">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: grid;` in your .HEADER with `grid-template-column: 75% auto;` - says first column (first child-element of .HEADER) is width of 75% (of its parent-element's width) and `auto` to set the second column (second child-element of .HEADER) fill the rest of parents element's width.

```css
    html{
        height: 900px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    body{
        height: 885px;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 5px;
    }


    .MAINPAGE{
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 870px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .HEADER{
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 175px;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 75% auto;
        grid-gap: 5px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .headerLeftPanel{
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 160px;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .headerRightPanel{
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin: 5px;
    }

    .signIn{
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 30px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="MAINPAGE">
          <div class="HEADER">
            <div class="headerLeftPanel">
              
            </div>
            <div class="headerRightPanel">
              <div class="signIn">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```